How to Refactor T-SQL Code to Databricks SQL Undefined function: 'IIF'
When executing the following T-SQL code with Databricks SQL I get the error:
Undefined function: 'IIF'.
,ISNULL(RH.Exchange, ISNULL(IIF(SIB.Rate = 0, 1, CASE .....

This is because Databricks doesn't recognize IIF. Can someone let me know the equivalent with Databricks SQL?

In databricks SQL , you can use iff function to acheive the same requirement of T-SQL's iif function.
Syntax for iff function:
iff(cond, expr1, expr2)

here,
cond: a Boolean expression,
expr1: any expression which needs to be executed when the cond is true,
expr2: any expression which needs to be executed when the cond is false.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/iff

Hi @Aswin, thanks for reaching out. I just attempted your suggestion with the following code...  ,ISNULL(RH.ExchangeRateLocal, ISNULL(iif(cond, SIB.ExchangeRate = 0, 1, CASE...
But I'm not getting the error  Undefined function: 'iif'.

Can you put iff not iif

Oops, I will put iff instead of iif and let you know how I get on. Thanks @Aswin

replacing iif with iff worked. Thank you

Great to know , this works for you
